# Animate a background image in an overlay

Tags: css, animated-gif

I followed another stackoverflow answer to create a loading overlay in my webpage.  I have my overlay class as:

```
.overlay {
  display:    none;
  position:   fixed;
  z-index:    1000;
  top:        0;
  left:       0;
  height:     100%;
  width:      100%;
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 )
              url('../images/loaderIcon.png')
              50% 50%
              no-repeat;
}
```

I also have a css class that animates whatever it is attached to to spin:

```
.spinning {
  animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: spin2 1s infinite linear;
}
```

Now, in the stackoverflow answer, they used a .gif file from imgur.  I created my own image that I want to use, and I wanted to animate it to spin.  Obviously, just attaching this class to the overlay class makes the entire overlay spin (which, admittedly, is hilarious).  Is there a way to just isolate the background URL source to spin?  Is there an easy way for me to convert it to a gif and animate it using another program? (MacOS)

Comment: `Is there a way to just isolate the background URL source to spin?` --> you have the answer, isolate it alone as one element and spin it

Comment: Sorry, CSS isn't my strong suit.  You mean make the source image spin, or just put the image element in my <div> tag that will contain the class?

Comment: just put the image in its own div, there is no way to spin only a part of an element

Comment: I will try that, thanks!